# What things should I look before migrating to a new web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, migration

I've to migrate an apache web server, from a small startup which previous developers resigned, without leaving any documentation.

What things should I look for, in order to minimize the risk of letting something behind? (The original one will still be accessible for a few days, but the DNS will be pointing to the new one)

I already thought of the following items:

- *(obviously)* web document root files
- Virtual hosts configuration
- crons
- PHP and Apache settings and installed libraries

I already migrated the separate DB server (there's no local db).

Answer (score 2):

I think those are the main things.  But I don't think any list is as important or useful as migration testing.  Set up a staging environment with your new web and database servers, migrate the application, and test it.  When it passes your tests, you can have some confidence that it's ready for production.  And you can do load testing in the new environment at the same time.

Comment: Although the creation of a staging environment is planned, it isn't a simple plug-and-play thing. The website uses a lot of apis, and have a lot of automated tasks. Having 2 running instances would provoke duplicated calls to a few external apis

Comment: Upvote. yep its pretty much the exact answer to the question, i.e. Ive got this complicated config with lots of moving parts - how do I know I havent missed anything? - use a staging environment - with VM's and a decent VPS host, they give you lots of options, "snapshot" a server, deploy to a temporary VM etc

Comment: What Michael Coleman said.